# Выбрать блок данных между определёнными строками

Tags: c#

Есть массив строк

```
string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
```

файл примерно следующего содержания:

```
1
строка1
строка2
строка3
строка4
строка5

2
строка1
строка2
строка3


3
строка1
строка2
4
строка1
строка2
строка3
5
строка1
6
итд..
```

нужно вытаскивать строки между цифрами в отдельные Span для последующей обработки.

сделал так:

```
            int counter = -1;
            int firstBlockLine = -1;
            int lastBlockLine = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if(int.TryParse(Lines[i],out int value))
            {
                if (counter < 0)
                {
                    counter = value; // first line in file
                    firstBlockLine = i;


                    continue;
                }

                counter++;

                if (counter <= value)
                {
                    
                    if (firstBlockLine >= 0)
                    {
                        lastBlockLine = i - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        firstBlockLine = i;
                    }
                }

                if (lastBlockLine > 0 && firstBlockLine >= 0)
                {                        
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Block begin:{firstBlockLine}, end:{lastBlockLine}");
                    firstBlockLine = -1;
                    lastBlockLine = -1;
                }
            }
```

Но в этом варианте пропускается каждый второй блок.
как мне получить индексы начала и конца всех блоков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то много наворотили. Или отладка, или начать с простого:

```
last = 999999999;
for(int i = 0; i <= Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i==Lines.Length ||  int.TryParse(Lines[i],out int value))
        {
            if (i > last)
                Debug.WriteLine($"Block begin:{last}, end:{i}");
            last = i;
        }
    }
```

Если работает, то подкорректировать индексы для вывода

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    int parse = 0;
    var idx = Lines.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v }).Where(x => int.TryParse(x.Value, out parse)).Select(x => x.Index);
    foreach (var i in idx)
        Debug.WriteLine(i);
```

Вывод на вашем примере:

```
0
7
13
16
20
22
```